# How to determin the right reply URL for Windows UWP app?

Tags: xaml, azure, uwp, azure-active-directory

I can't seem to recall how but my Azure AD is setup with a reply url for my Windows UPW app that looks like this:

> ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/S-1-15-2-{RANDOM_CHARACTERS}

I am now getting the following error message:

> AADSTS50011: The reply address
>   'ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/S-1-15-2-{RANDOM_CHARACTERS}'
>   doesn't match the reply addresses configured for the application:
>   {different_GUID}

I don't recognize the {different_GUID} but I do know that the 'ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/S-1-15-2-{RANDOM_CHARACTERS}' is the reply URL I have setup in Azure AD. The weird thing is, some of my developers can login okay while others it is failing.

UPDATE:

That link really helped. This simple line of text helped me get the URL so I could compare it with what I had registered in Azure AD originally (it was a while ago)

```
    string URI = string.Format("ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugIn/{0}", WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().Host.ToUpper());
```

I found out that the old URL I had setup in Azure AD was different so I'm guessing that is the problem. I think it might of changed because I did the "Right Click->Store->Association App in Store"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect URI of a UWP app is assigned by the system - by Visual Studio at creation time, and by the store at publication time. You have to first find out what URI your app got, using the instructions in the readme in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-wam/tree/master/NativeClient-UWP-WAM, then you have to record it in Azure AD. Perhaps one of your developers started a new project - which would result in a new URI assigned and a mismatch with what's already recorded in Azure AD.

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation. I am transitioning my app from the deprecated MS Application Registration Portal to the Azure Portal, which now requires a reply URL. I never would have figured this out on my own. Thank you!